# Wrong ELF number with libwebdriverxxx

Tags: apt, 20.04, error-handling

I am facing this issue while doing any `apt` request:

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/lib/libwebdriverxx.so is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.
```

I tried doing:

```
sudo apt-get purge libwebdriver
```

but the package is not there. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Move the problematic library out the way by

```
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libwebdriverxx.so ~/
sudo ldconfig
```

and retry.